# AWS CDK - Typescript optional parameters in Interface error: TS2532

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm trying to implement optional parameters in interface, however I get an error **TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.**, is there any way to implement optional properties like in this [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#property-modifiers)

Here are my interfaces:

```
// Local interface
interface SecondaryIndex {
         secondaryIndexName: string;
         addLocalSecondaryIndex: boolean;
}

// Exported Interface
export interface ILambdas extends cdk.StackProps {
  ...
  secondaryIndex?: SecondaryIndex
}
```

Error: TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined':

```
if (props.secondaryIndex.addLocalSecondaryIndex) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript's [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator (`?.`) to the rescue!

```js
if (props.secondaryIndex?.addLocalSecondaryIndex) {
    ...
}
```

With `?.`, if `secondaryIndex` is `undefined` your conditional expression evaluates to `undefined` rather than throwing an Error.  Typescript will be happy.